# Change jsGrid insertvalue based on select control on the page

Tags: javascript, jsgrid

I am using JsGrid in my asp.net application. I felt it was very awesome grid. Everything worked out very well, but I was stuck at one point.

I have a dropdown on a page which is fetching data from database. and next to that control, i have added JsGrid.

When I change the index of dropdown, and when I click on Add row on my jsgrid, it should set the default value for one of the fields in the grid.

Can anybody please help me out in this regard.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcsC1.png)

Regards,
Nithin Eate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redefine `insertTemplate` of the grid column you want to set default value to and pick up value from your dropdown widget:

```
insertTemplate: function() {
    var input = this.__proto__.insertTemplate.call(this); // original input

    // getValueFromDropDown() should read value from your dropdown control
    var defaultValue = getValueFromDropDown();

    input.val(defaultValue)

    return input;
}
```

The source GitHub issue https://github.com/tabalinas/jsgrid/issues/471